# React Not Displaying / Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I recently started learning React. I wanted to make my first app and have done the following.

1. Created a project folder
2. Ran npx create-react-app App.js
3. Ran npm start

My src/App.js is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const navbar = (
    <nav>
        <h1>Wiggly's</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Menu</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(navbar);
```

My index.html is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>

    <script src="App.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

When I refresh my localhost I still see the react splash screen.

I've looked everywhere on the forums and haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. It's my first time using react so I'm likely making a simple error. I appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have created the app using CRA, Can you check if there is already a `root.render()` method being called inside the `index.js` file which is showing the splash screen.

The default template of CRA has the `root.render` method inside the `index.js` file with `App` imported from `App.js` file.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response. How would I check this? I poked around in chrome dev tools a bit but I don't see anything there.

Comment: You can just check that in your code in your IDE.

Comment: I see it now. I do have a root.render displaying the splash screen inside my index.js. Should I overwrite my index.js code with my app.js code in that case?

Comment: Ack, I just realized I created an App.js one level up. I did not realize another App.js would be created when I ran CRA. I think I know how to fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed following the [naming convention](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type) that React component needs.

From the docs

> Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component.

Changing `const navbar = (` to `const Navbar = (` should work.

Try checking in incognito mode, check for console errors if any if its still not working as expected.

Comment: Clearly I did miss that. I must have seen people use capital letters but not realize it was mandatory, and subsequently not know what was wrong.

I changed const Navbar as well as root.render(Navbar), but after saving my work and refreshing the tab I still get the splash screen.

Comment: ok. Would you be able to provide a codesandbox link or any such which we can look at. Also do you see any errors in console?

Comment: I get no errors in the console.
Code sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-visvesvaraya-x60vcw?file=/src/App.js

I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake. I apologize for the ineptitude, I'm still a beginner and learning a lot each day. Thank you.

Comment: That's not a problem. Everyone is a learner in the beginning. Let me see what the codesandbox has.